# iOS Simulator not running app, only showing a black screen

Tags: ios, performance, ios-simulator

I'm running my app, and it has no errors. The simulator is only showing a black screen.

[image]

Has this happened to anyone? How do you fix it? By the way, this is after I launch my app from the home screen.

Comment: If you hit shift-cmd-h, are you taken to the home screen?  If so, it's likely a bug in your app.  If not, it's possible that the SimDevice was shutdown since older versions of Simulator did not close the window when an external process shutdown the device.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have an error message?
2. If not, then try one of the following article about cleaning XCode cash and how-to reset the simulator:

   - [How to really clean you xcode build](http://samwize.com/2015/07/10/how-to-really-clean-your-xcode-build/)
   - [Clean Xcode cache quick fix](http://www.developerinsider.in/clean-xcode-cache-quick-fix/)
   - [Xcode 7 Reset simulator](https://briancoyner.github.io/2015/11/09/xcode7-reset-simulator.html)

There is also an app [Xcode Cache Clean](http://www.packal.org/workflow/xcode-cache-clean)

Answer (score 0):

You can **Reset Content and Settings** from top left . This may help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had this same problem with a project I was migrating from Swift 3 to Swift 4.2. The problem was the method signatures on `AppDelegate`, specifically the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which I had to change from:

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

To:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

This solved the issue. The simulator (and device) showed a black screen because `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` was not executed. Consequently, the `UIWindow.rootViewController` was not set.